# what is pilot estimator?

Tags: statistics, estimation

I have met with a term **"pilot estimator"** in some papers .I have no idea what it is and I have searched the website like wiki but in vain. Can anybody tell me what it is ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might helpfully include some links showing this usage.  But I would guess it could mean something like "estimator used in the pilot phase" or "preliminary estimator" or "initial estimator"

Comment: @Henry Honestly , I find it in the manuscript from my supervisor saying **"the pilot estimator of covariance function is ..."** without any explansation of the **"pilot estimator"** . So I suppose you are right that it means the initial estimator. Thank you very much.